# Timeout interval not set for POST requests on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, timeout, alamofire, moya

I have a timeOutInterval set to 30 seconds on all my requests via this code:

```
class DefaultAlamofireSession: Alamofire.Session {
    static let shared: DefaultAlamofireSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
        return DefaultAlamofireSession(configuration: configuration)
    }()
}
```

While testing, I noticed that only my GET requests get timed out at 30 seconds. My POST requests are still using the default interval which is 60 seconds.

Can anyone explain why and possibly tell me how I can make the POST requests also time out at 60 seconds?

Thanks a lot,
Paprika

Answer (score 1):

`URLSessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest` does not do what you think it does. From Apple's docs:

> This property determines the request timeout interval for all tasks within sessions based on this configuration. The request timeout interval controls how long (in seconds) a task should wait for additional data to arrive before giving up. The timer associated with this value is reset whenever new data arrives. When the request timer reaches the specified interval without receiving any new data, it triggers a timeout.

So that property only controls the timeout *between* chunks of response `Data`. That's not typically what you want. Instead, you want to set the `URLRequest.timeoutInterval` directly, which does more of what you want.

> If during a connection attempt the request remains idle for longer than the timeout interval, the request is considered to have timed out. The default timeout interval is 60 seconds.

As you can see, this timeout applies to the connection *attempt*, which is what most people think of as a request's timeout.

You can customize this value in Alamofire by applying a `RequestAdapter` to your custom `Session`. Or, you can use the `requestModifier` closure that available on the various `request*` methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you give a code example of how you would use the RequestAdapter or requestModifier to do that?